# How to search in all Table in Mysql database?

Tags: android

I want to search in all table with name how i can make that in android ? 
i want to use searchview

i searched but i didn't find anything

this activity where i display data from one table and i use search in this table only i want to use search in all table and display in another activity

### Activity

```
public class R_arabic extends AppCompatActivity
    implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

String story_type;
String story_type2;

ProgressBar progressBar;
LinearLayout progress_layout;

List<listitem_gib> GetDataAdapter1;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewadapter;

String id = "id";
String name = "name";
String url = "url";
String img = "img";
String num = "num";
String size = "size";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
RequestQueue requestQueue ;
ImageView banner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_r_arabic);

    banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    story_type2 = intent.getStringExtra("Story_Type2");

    switch (story_type2) {
        case "روايات رومانسية":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.romance_banner);
            break;
        case "روايات عربية":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.arabic_banner);
            break;
        case "روايات رعب":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.ro3b_banner);
            break;
        case "روايات مترجمة":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.motrgam_banner);
            break;
        case "روايات سياسية":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.siasa_banner);
            break;
        case "روايات جيب":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.gib_banner);
            break;
        case "كتب تنيمة بشرية":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.tnmia_banner);
            break;
        case "كتب اسلامية":
            banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.islam_banner);
            break;
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(story_type2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
    progress_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
    progress_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
}


public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    story_type = intent.getStringExtra("Story_Type");

    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://i-geeky.info/android/" + story_type + ".php";

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    progress_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        listitem_gib GetDataAdapter2 = new listitem_gib();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetDataAdapter2.setId(json.getString(id));
            GetDataAdapter2.setName(json.getString(name));
            GetDataAdapter2.seturl(json.getString(url));
            GetDataAdapter2.setimg(json.getString(img));
            GetDataAdapter2.setnum(json.getString(num));
            GetDataAdapter2.setsize(json.getString(size));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }
    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);

    //RecyclerView needs a layout manager in order to display data so here we create one
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //Here we set the layout manager and the adapter to the listview
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
    searchView.setQueryHint("ادخل اسم الروايه او اسم الكاتب");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    newText = newText.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\u0624", "\u0648").replaceAll("\u0629", "\u0647").replaceAll("\u064a", "\u0649")
            .replaceAll("\u0626", "\u0649").replaceAll("\u0622", "\u0627")
            .replaceAll("\u0623", "\u0627").replaceAll("\u0625", "\u0627");
    List<listitem_gib> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (listitem_gib list : GetDataAdapter1){
        String name = list.getName().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\u0624", "\u0648").replaceAll("\u0629", "\u0647").replaceAll("\u064a", "\u0649")
                .replaceAll("\u0626", "\u0649").replaceAll("\u0622", "\u0627")
                .replaceAll("\u0623", "\u0627").replaceAll("\u0625", "\u0627");
        String name1 = list.getnum().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\u0624", "\u0648").replaceAll("\u0629", "\u0647").replaceAll("\u064a", "\u0649")
                .replaceAll("\u0626", "\u0649").replaceAll("\u0622", "\u0627")
                .replaceAll("\u0623", "\u0627").replaceAll("\u0625", "\u0627");

        if (name.contains(newText) || name1.contains(newText)){
            newList.add(list);
        }
    }
    recyclerViewadapter.setFilter(newList);
    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute SQL command with Cursor's method with your SQL Commands.

e.g.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from tab");
```